# Наложение прозрачной текстовой маски на анимированный прогресс-бар (SVG)

Tags: css, анимация, svg, animate, mask

У меня такая проблема, что не удается совместить прозрачную текстовую маску и прогресс-бар: получается либо статичная прозрачная маска либо аниминированный прогресс-бар без надписи.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы был фоновый круг и круг заполняющий (прогресс-бар) с наложенной маской-текстом, через которую должен быть виден фон сайта, независимо от количества слоёв (в данном случае кругов).

Круг с прозрачной маской.

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 160 900" width="100" height="100%"> 
    <defs>
      <mask id="myMask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
        <text x="19" y="85" style="font-size:35" id="myText1">HTML</text>

      </mask>
    </defs>

    <circle id="masked" r="65" style=" mask: url(#myMask)" fill="rgb(216, 106, 247)" cx="70" cy="70" />
    
</svg>
```

[image: mask]

И прогресс-бар.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 360 160" width="360" height="160">
      <defs>
       <clipPath id="left-to-right">
           <rect x="130" y="30" width="100" height="0">
           <animate attributeName="height" values="100;50" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>   
         </rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle cx="180" cy="80" r="50" fill="red"/>
      <circle cx="180" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#left-to-right)"/>
     </svg>
```

[image: bar]

Моя попытка их совместить.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 360 160" width="360" height="160">
      <defs>
          <mask id="myMask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <text x="19" y="85" id="myText1"  style="font-size:35" >HTML</text>
          </mask>
       <clipPath id="filling">
           <rect x="130" y="30" width="100" height="0">
           <animate attributeName="height" values="100;10" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>   
         </rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle id="masked" cx="180" cy="80" r="50" fill="red"/>
      <circle id="masked" cx="180" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#filling)"/>
     </svg>
```

Подскажите, куда нужно вставлять маску, чтобы всё заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку вы не используете [`maskContentUnits = objectBoundingBox`](http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/#maskUnits) , координаты фильтра рассчитываются *глобально* (относительно документа). И если вы сдвинули круг, неудивительно, что текст на маске теперь в него не попадает. Прошерcтите координаты элементов так, чтобы они попадали друг в друга, или попробуйте переделать фильтры под *относительные* координаты.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 360 160" width="360" height="160">
      <defs>
          <mask id="myMask">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <text x="38" y="90" id="myText1" style="font-size:30"  >HTML</text>
          </mask>
          <clipPath id="filling">
            <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="0">
               <animate attributeName="height" values="100;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>   
            </rect>
          </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="red" mask="url(#myMask)" />
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#filling)"  mask="url(#myMask)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<body>
<style>
body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTvBfG3RU9FtABFmZQeqeNjnb0twz5xSvGIKFcgsAGew35Rj9NFw') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#container2 
{
 float:left;
}
#container3 
{
 float:left;
}
#txt
{
color:white;
}
</style
<div id="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
     
  <defs>
          <mask id="maskText">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <text x="38" y="90" id="myText1" style="font-size:36"  >Html</text>
          </mask>
          <clipPath id="filling">
            <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="0">
               <animate attributeName="height" begin="svg1.click" values="100;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>   
            </rect>
          </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="lime" opacity="0.6" mask="url(#maskText)" />
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#filling)"  mask="url(#maskText)" />
</svg>
</div>
<div id="container2">
<svg id="svg2" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160" >
     
  <defs>
          <mask id="maskText2">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <text x="60" y="90" id="myText1" style="font-size:36"  >JS</text>
          </mask>
          <clipPath id="filling2">
            <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="0">
               <animate attributeName="height" begin="svg2.click" values="100;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>   
            </rect>
          </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="crimson" opacity="0.6" mask="url(#maskText2)" />
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#filling2)"  mask="url(#maskText2)" />
</svg>
<svg id="svg3" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 160 160" >
     
  <defs>
          <mask id="maskText3">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
            <text x="45" y="90" id="myText1" style="font-size:36"  >PHP</text>
          </mask>
          <clipPath id="filling3">
            <rect x="30" y="30" width="100" height="0">
               <animate attributeName="height" begin="svg3.click" values="100;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>   
            </rect>
          </clipPath>
      </defs> 
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="yellow" opacity="0.6" mask="url(#maskText3)" />
      <circle id="masked" cx="80" cy="80" r="50" fill="black" clip-path="url(#filling3)"  mask="url(#maskText3)" />
</svg>
</div>

</body>
```

Я так понял вопрос и немного доработал решение Crantisz . Для анимации кликайте по пунктам меню.

Comment: @Riccu видимо здесь запрещена правилами безопастности динамическая подгрузка файлов. Не работает здесь смена фона. На локальной машине всё работает, смотрится довольно занятно. Если это для веб странички, то нужно подобрать более подходящий фон, чтобы буквы маски лучше смотрелись

Comment: @RiccuУстановил статический фон. Для добавления подгрузки картинок - `http://placeimg.com/480/160/any') no-repeat;`

Comment: Ответ выше то, что я имел ввиду. Но вам тоже спасибо за интересный эффект, он мне пригодится)

Comment: @Riccu и вам спасибо за интересный вопрос. Задавайте больше вопросов не стесняйтесь. У меня сложилось впечатление, что тут работают такие отличные специалисты, которые могут красиво ответить на большинство сложных вопросов. Не забывайте только благодарить людей, которые потратят на ваши вопросы время.